# DNSSEC problems in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dns, 17.04, systemd-resolved

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04.
In the installer, I connected to a wifi, but the installation process could not connect, saying `DNSSEC validation failed`.
The same situation was in the installed system.

I found [an article recommending to turn of DNSSEC](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/): `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and add `DNSSEC=off`.

I understand the value of DNSSEC, but why it's not working in Ubuntu right away? Even the Ubuntu servers couldn't be contacted by the installer, which, to me, seems like a blocker for releasing the version.

So I assume this is triggered by my local conditions? How? How can I make DNSSEC work? The article recommended getting rid of `systemd-resolved` and installing Unbound.

Comment: This impacted me also. I am using a ATT UVerse PACE gateway router, which probably doesn't support it.